# python opencv - How to combine two contours

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I want cut up the captcha image.
the origin picture is here:
[captcha url](http://railway.hinet.net/ImageOut.jsp)

There are my results:
[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

First,I remove noise and line from captcha.
Then find contours. 
I draw contours in image using green line.
But some chars in image will separated in two piece.
How to determine two piece is belong to one char?

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(self.im, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
```

Comment: Calculate the centroid of every contour. Find closest distance between each of them. If the centroids appear to be too close to each other, consider joining the corresponding contours

Comment: thank you for your help.I will try it